# How can I quantify the difference of meaning of two terms? For example "bird" and "Chair"

Tags: nlp, semantics, ontology

Edited:
I have some terms/topics and I want to quantify how different these terms/topics are in meaning or domain from each other. Following is the use case in which I want to apply it:

Right now I have dataset from twitter about a particular cricket match (tweets with hashtag of this match). I want to see how many other topics, unrelated to cricket match, make their way in such tweets. For example if someone starts taking about "Syrian Refuges" in such tweet that will not be very related to the topic of game Cricket. 
My basic approach is to extract topics from these tweets and then identify which topics are closely related to domain of cricket and which ones are not.

Comment: This question sounds deeper than scope of NLP in Stackoverflow :). Maybe you can give us your use-case for such quantification.

Comment: Hi @Mehdi, Right now I have dataset from twitter. The tweets are about cricket match. I want to identify how many other topics make there way in such tweets. So basically I will extract the topics from tweets and then see how unrelated these topics are from domain of "Cricket".

Answer (score 1):

Statistically, you can look at [word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html), [fasttext](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText), and similar models. Here "difference" can be the distance (euclidean or cosine similarity) between two points in the vector space. In short, you load your corpus in an engine which creates an n-dimensional space, placing words (and sometimes documents or char n-grams) as points in the space in such way that words appearing in similar contexts have close representations (vectors).

One drawback of most such representations is that antonyms often appear close to each other: For instance in "I love you" and "I hate you", love and hate have very similar contexts.

From a semantic point of view, as you added the tag ontology, you can use a structured knowledge base or ontology. One option is to define "distance" in the taxonomy between the two terms. You can check if they appear on the same level as siblings, one is parent of the other or other relations. I believe the most straight-forward way is to manually define weights for each relation, but maybe statistical approaches for graphs traversing and clustering are also appropriate.

For classes you can use number of instances you have and any relations between those instances. For instance, you can calculate distance between "bird" and "chair" by the number of instances of birds and chairs for which you have relation "sits on". Hopefully "person" and "chair" will be much closer as most of your person objects will have a designated "chair" object.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any existing taxonomies and ontologies? As far as i know ontoligies are domain specific and for noew domain you have to create new ontologies

Comment: You can check  https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/ (former Freebase), http://wiki.dbpedia.org/, or http://linkeddata.org/

Answer (score 1):

To have a quick look you can use bird-noun-1 and chair-noun-1 and wordnet at:
http://labs.fc.ul.pt/dishin/
it gives you:

Resnik  0.315625756544

Lin 0.0574161071905

Jiang&Conrath 0.0964964414156

The python code: https://github.com/lasigeBioTM/DiShIn